# Computer not starting, giving 3 or 4 beep notifications

Tags: desktop-computer

My computer won't start anymore. It has sometimes given me 3 beeps - pause - 3 beeps again, but after 2-3 tries it still managed to boot.

I tried changing RAM positions and only using one at a time, nothing changed but it worked so I just put everything back.

Today I got 4 beeps and nothing was working anymore. Again, I tried changing the RAM positions and using only one (trying different ones) but I can't get my computer to work again.
Here's what happens now:

4 RAMs set: 4 beeps

Not all 4 RAMs set: 3 beeps, no matter which or how many RAMs are plugged in

Obviously I googled to find that stuff over RAM, but it seems like this is not a RAM issue as the computer may had problems for some time, but it still worked. Now i tried everything with the RAM and it still won't work.

I have read things about changing the battery or that it could be an issue with the video card. Can someone please give me ideas on what I should do next?

EDIT: AMI Board

Comment: Since you already tried many RAM combinations, you could try removing your video card and replacing the CMOS battery. If you continue to have problems, I would guess the motherboard is going bad since it is so inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

#### 3 or 4 beep notifications

Assuming you have an AMI BIOS (likely as you have an AMI Motherboard) then memory could still be the problem:

[image]

Source [AMI BIOS Beep Codes](http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/amibeep.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it help if I would use a complete different RAM module in this case?

Comment: @Andreas It is worth a try ...